# Class Library (Portable for Universal Apps) System.Threading.Thread limitations

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I use Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4 to create a new project of type "Class Library (Portable for Universal Apps)". The resulting PCL is targeted at two platforms i.e. Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 and this is what I need.

[System.Threading.Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) class is not supported in this subset.
When I widen the assembly targeting with two more platforms (.NET Framework 4.5.1 and Silverlight 5) the System.Threading.Thread mystically shows up and becomes available.
I tried to use it and it works perfectly being run by both Windows.Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 Store apps.

Did I get it right that the System.Threading.Thread class is simply hidden from the "default" PCL configuration in order to push developers towards async/await pattern?

Leaving behind the comparison of advantages and draws of different asynchronous execution and thread management models, are there any technical drawbacks in utilizing the System.Threading.Thread class in the mentioned scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use the Thread class, and can't do the same thing with Task? What you're doing is a bit hacky. If you truly need it and it works - fine, but if you don't need it, you better switch to tasks.

Comment: Can you try running the app through the Store certification (WACK) to see if it passes?

Comment: @PeterTorr I ran the Windows App Certification Kit 3.4 against my application and it successfully passed all the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some discussion with [David Kean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218765/david-kean) from the .NET team, this is expected behaviour but note that you do **not** get access to the full .NET `Thread` class; you only get a couple of things like `ManagedThreadId` and `CurrentUICulture`.

So you still need to use either the thread pool or the task-based APIs in order to run parallel operations.

Comment: It would be great to get David's opinion on the second matter of the like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660915/class-library-portable-for-universal-apps-system-diagnostics-stacktrace-limita