# Class Library (Portable for Universal Apps) System.Diagnostics.StackTrace limitations and referencing assemblies targeted at another runtime

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I use Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4 to create a new project of type "Class Library (Portable for Universal Apps)". The resulting PCL is targeted at two platforms i.e. Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 and this is what I need.

[System.Diagnostics.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx) class is not supported in this subset. For my other applications I heavily utilize this class for purposes of tracing and exception logging. After a while of trial and error I found out that I can simply set a reference from my Windows Phone 8.1 Store App or from a PCL targeted at Windows 8.1/Windows Phone 8.1 to an assembly targeted at Silverlight 5 and in that referenced assembly I can utilize the System.Diagnostics.StackTrace class and this actually works.

Are there any technical drawbacks in utilizing the System.Diagnostics.StackTrace class in the mentioned scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a reference fails Windows App Certification Kit 3.4 "Supported API test"

> This API is not supported for this application type - Api=System.Diagnostics.StackTrace. Module=MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=7CEC85D7BEA7798E. File=MyLib1.dll.

Comment: As you say, it fails the WACK test and is not supported in Windows Store apps. For a limited set of scenarios, consider using [`CallerMemberNameAttrubute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), especially for logging where you just want the immediate caller.